# Are uppercase utf8 characters always the same number of bytes as their lowercase variants?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, case-insensitive

Obviously it is true for the latin alphabet.  But I'm asking this in a conceptual sense, across languages and the Unicode spec.

Practically this came up for comparing two strings.  If you already know they aren't the same number of bytes—across all languages—can you consider that enough of a guarantee that they are not differently "cased" versions of the same string?

Comment: Note that uppercase utf-8 strings can even have a different number of *characters* than their lowercase equivalent: 'ß' -> 'SS'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No.

Consider U+0069 "i" which has the octet value `69` in UTF-8. In the uppercase form U+0130 "İ" this code point forms the UTF-8 sequence `C4 B0`.

*Obligatory note: case is locale-sensitive.*

Comment: I know little about Unicode and the ways of the world in this respect.  But is it typical/valid to lose information in uppercase/lowercase transformations?  If you can't uniquely convert back and forth, is it fair to call those both "cases of the same letter"?

Comment: 'i' and 'I' are both one byte. But U+0130 is the special capital I for Turkish. To people there, they are 'two cases of the same letter'.

Comment: @bmargulies Good to know...well then, I guess you have to go through and look at each character to do a case-insensitive comparison, then.

Comment: @HostileFork I recommend the [Unicode FAQ](http://www.unicode.org/faq/casemap_charprop.html) on case mapping - and [section 5.18](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.2.0/ch05.pdf#G21180) of the Unicode spec - for more info.

Answer (score 5):

There is no principle or invariant in the Unicode standard that guarantees this. I would be particularly concerned about accented capitals, where there may be a mismatch between precomposition and non-precomposition across cases. However, I can't cite an example of a problem for you.