# Is uppercase string always of the same length as the original one?

Tags: c#, unicode

- Is the length of an unicode uppercase string always the same as the length of an original string, no matter what culture is used?
- Is the length of an unicode lowercase string always the same as the length of an original string, no matter what culture is used?

In other words, is the following true in C#?

```
text.ToUpper(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Length == text.Length
text.ToLower(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Length == text.Length
```

Note that I'm not interested about the number of bytes: [the question about that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14792841/240613) is already answered.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say "length", you really mean "the `Length` property of .NET's `System.String`". Because how string classes behave is often quite different from what Unicode specifies should happen (and there are many different ways to measure the "length" of a string) (And specificially, `System.String.Length` measures the number of UTF-16 code units in a string, and *not* the number of Unicode code points (which would be a more semantically correct measure of "string length")

Comment: The common uppercase version of the German word "gemäß" is "GEMÄSS".

Comment: Note, that the length in .NET chars is the length in UCS-2 chars, not in code points. Code points are the actual unicode characters. So string.Length is not that meaningful for i18n applications.

Comment: @jalf: I mean the `Length` property of a string in .NET.

Comment: Also, as a good rule of thumb, for any question "can I assume X to be true for any Unicode string", the answer is "no" :)

Comment: I'm sure it would be possible to create a culture which changes the length (or anything else).

Comment: @Jongware, nevertheless "gemäß".ToUpper() is "GEMÄß"

Comment: @Joe: it's a German rule and as such you should apply German locale settings "using the casing rules of the specified culture." ([MSDN on String.ToUpper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24kc78ka(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: .. Although my German example *does* lead to `"gemäß".toUpper().toLower() != "gemäß"` ...

Comment: @Joe: apologies -- according to MSDN my particular example is still under review (since 2010), see hvd's answer below.

Comment: .NET uppercasing is a bit buggy.  ""eﬀect".ToUpper() produces "EﬀECT".  Taking a dependency on those bugs *never* getting fixed is unwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can give a partial answer. For all strings of length 2 (of which there are about 4 billion), and for the German culture (`de-DE`) your assertions hold:

```
    static unsafe void TestUnicodeLength2()
    {
        Parallel.For(char.MinValue, char.MaxValue + 1, charVal =>
        {
            var firstChar = checked((char)charVal);
            var buffer = new string(firstChar, 2);

            fixed (char* bufferPtr = buffer)
            {
                var currentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

                for (int i = char.MinValue; i <= char.MaxValue; i++)
                {
                    bufferPtr[1] = checked((char)i);

                    var toLower = buffer.ToLower(currentCulture);
                    if (toLower.Length != buffer.Length)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(buffer + " => " + toLower);
                        Debugger.Break();
                    }

                    var toUpper = buffer.ToUpper(currentCulture);
                    if (toUpper.Length != buffer.Length)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(buffer + " => " + toUpper);
                        Debugger.Break();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

This runs for about 2 minutes.

I think this is rather strong evidence that the assertions always hold because by testing all possible combinations of two chars we automatically test all code points in existence and all strange combinations that no one would ever think about.

Update: I later ran a similar test for random strings (each 256 chars in length) for 256 billion characters in total length. The assertions still hold.

Comment: Good answer, but it is worth clarifying that (1) you are talking about the characteristics of .NET, and not of Unicode (When read literally, the question was about Unicode, but clearly in a .NET context, so the answer is still relevant)), and that (2) this is based on how .NET behaves *today*, which could be due to an incomplete implementation, or just plain bugs. Still, actually just running the test and seeing how it *actually* behaves here and now is definitely worthwhile. It's just also important to keep in mind what it *doesn't* tell us.

Comment: @jalf you're 100% right. This is a very partial answer and I'd only rely on its result in case its correctness is not 100% important. I'd never base decisions about security or life and death on this result.

Answer (score 5):

The answers to the questions are “No” and “Yes”, as far as Unicode Standard is concerned.

For example, when converting to uppercase, “ß” U+00DF LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S is mapped to two characters “SS” by Unicode mapping rules. It is possible to map it to the single character “ẞ” U+1E9E LATIN CAPITAL LETTER SHARP S, but that’s not the default (and not common at all). Another example is that “ﬁ” U+FB01 LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FI is mapped to “FI”.

In the opposite direction, there is no default mapping that would change the number of characters. See [Character Properties, Case Mappings & Names FAQ](http://www.unicode.org/faq/casemap_charprop.html), which links to the file [SpecialCasing.txt](ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/SpecialCasing.txt) that contains all deviations from simple one-to-one mappings. The only rules there that would make the lowercase string different from an uppercase original are a few *optional* rules related to Lithuanian practices.

Comment: Good answer. .NET does not seem to implement any of these rules at the moment, at least not in the culture I tested.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, this is true. The .NET developers have decided to use the Windows APIs for Unicode, and those don't support case conversions that change the length of a string.

This is not a guarantee by the .NET team that it will always remain so, though. If Windows gets new APIs that do support those conversions, .NET may be updated to use them.

See [System.String.ToUpper() doesn't follow UNICODE SpecialCasing](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/619924/system-string-toupper-doesnt-follow-unicode-specialcasing) on Microsoft Connect.

Comment: So it is true ATM but *should be*, and may one day *become*, false.