# Why does C# .ToLower not change the ASCII value of the string?

Tags: c#, string

I was trying to create a method to find the amount of duplicate characters in a string.  So, for example, `DuplicateCount("aabbcde")` would return 2 and `DuplicateCount("aabBcde")` would also return 2. My first thought to create this method was to convert the whole string to lowercase and then count how many times the characters appear based on their ASCII values.  So here is my code:

```
public static int DuplicateCount(string str)
{
    int[] buffer = new int[128]; //128 possible ASCII characters
    string lower = str.ToLower();
    int dups = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        int num = (int)str[i];
        buffer[num]++; //increase 
        if (buffer[num] == 2)
        {
            dups++;
        }
    }
    return dups;
}
```

This method won't work when the string contains uppercase characters. The reason why this method doesn't work is because the `str.ToLower()` call does not change the ASCII value of the characters, even though the string itself is changed to all lower case.  Does anyone know why this would be the case? And how would you get around it?

Comment: Strings are immutable. You are comparing two different objects.

Comment: Is it because the line `int num = (int)str[i];` should be `int num = (int)lower[i];`?

Comment: @yinnonsanders - Yes, and the `for` loop should be checking `lower.Length` as well.

Comment: @AdamV I agree that it should, but theoretically it shouldn't matter, because `ToLower` doesn't change the length of the string

Comment: @yinnonsanders Is that necessarily true?  The `Length` property gives the number of UTF-16 code units in the string, not the number of actual characters or codepoints.  And there's just enough weird stuff in Unicode to make me doubt whether `ToLower` would necessarily leave the `Length` property unchanged.

Comment: @Kyle According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301347/is-uppercase-string-always-of-the-same-length-as-the-original-one the `Length` is the same, but that is an interesting question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This happens because you used `str` instead of `lower` in your loop. `ToLower()` only returns a copy of a modified string (which you obviously saved, but didn't use).

Comment: `int num = (int)lower[i];`

Comment: @BrandonMinner Perhaps you should use a tool that tells you about incomplete thoughts like assigning a value to a variable and then not using that value—and a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int DuplicateCount(string str) {
    string strLower = str.ToLower();
    int dups = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < strLower.Length; i++)
    {
        int num1 = (int)strLower[i];

        for (int j = i+1; j < strLower.Length - 1; j++ ) {
            int num2 = (int)strLower[j];

            if(num1 == num2) {
               dups++; // found
            }
            else{
               break; // not found
            }
        }
    }
    return dups;
}
```