# Can _wcslwr_s() alter the required buffer length

Tags: c++

I need to apply secure crt versions (*_s) of corresponding functions. I stumbled over `_wcslwr_s()` (convert to lower case) and wonder if there is any locale which might require a larger lower case buffer than the original one?

Otherwise I could not explain why `_wcslwr_s()` exists at all other than "Every memory manipulation function has a _s equivalent".

Comment: `larger lower case buffer than the original one` - https://stackoverflow.com/q/20301347/11683

Comment: *"Every memory manipulation function has a _s equivalent".*  Probably the correct explanation. Also note that the "enhanced security" is just slightly enhanced, and still requires that you pass the correct parameters. For example, if the program has a bug to pass a buffer that is too small, what stops if from also passing the wrong size? A small buffer with a large length parameter will still overwrite memory!